# d3.js json via ajax response using d3.json()

Tags: php, json, ajax, d3.js

im quite new to d3.js and I wanted to learn how to use it. I'm trying to implement this example : https://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/ .
This example uses a set amount of data from a json script called "wheel.json". Now, what I want to know is if its possible to use json data requested with ajax (which requests a php file) instead, that way I could see data directly from a database, and graph data would update each time the database values changes. It dind't work by executing a $.ajax jquery to the php script, calling a specific case for methods.

PHP code:

```
switch ($strMetodo) {

case('listBananas'): //controlling what I need to list

    $arrayBananasTO = BananaController::listBananas(
            $QueryParameters); //fetch all Bananas from DAO and store them in an array

    $row = CBananasCommon::iterateListBananas($arrayBananasTO); //fetch the array, and 
store each value to a row in a datatable

    $output['data'] = $row; //store fetched array, and naming json's array container as 'data'

    echo json_encode(utf8ize($output)); //echoing json


    break;

case('listApples'):

    $codBananaObtenido = $_POST['idBanana'];

    $arrayApplesTO = AppleController::listApples(
            $QueryParameters);

    $row = CApplesCommon::iterateListApples(
            $arrayApplesTO);

    $output['data'] = $row;
    echo json_encode(utf8ize($output));

    break;
```

}

JS Code:

```
d3.json($.ajax({
    url: "..url/to/script/example.php",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": {method: "listBananas"},
    "success": function (output) {
         return output;
    }}), function (r, i) {
    function l(n) {


    .......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to replace the line d3.json("wheel.json",...  with the url of my php script and echo a json response. That way, I only needed to write d3.json("../url/to/script/example.php,...; And I had to execute the json's echo out of a switch/case, otherwise it wouldn't work. One more thing: keep an eye on the json's echo, if its wrong, corrupted, too much Array-ish, it won't be recognized by d3. Use a json beautifier for such purpose. Thanks(?)